# Naming a synchronization object in c# for use with contention analysis

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, locking

I'm currently doing my synchronization using a locking object to write to a collection like this:

```
private void WSMessageEnqueue(object sender, MessageClass message)
    {
        if (isDisconnecting == true) return;
        lock (enqueueLockObject)
        {
            incomingMessageQueue.Enqueue(message);
        }
    }
```

Where the `enqueueLockObject` is a `private object` in the class. I have several of these as messages are enqueued by different threads for different functional units. In the contention explorer I can see the threads hitting the locks but the locks all have names like `Handle18`.

[image: Contention]

Is it possible to name the locks so I can identify them more easily?

Comment: IIRC Jon Skeet has a wrapper for named locks in MiscUtil: see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/locking.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no named lock available in c#. You could try using [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx), but it is generally much slower than Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit.

Take a look at the [link](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/locking.html) provided by Mark or alternatively you can write you you own class. A basic implementation may look like:

```
public class NamedSyncRoot
{
    private object _syncRoot;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public NamedSyncRoot(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _syncRoot = new object();
    }

    public void Lock()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_syncRoot);
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private static NamedSyncRoot namedLock = new NamedSyncRoot("Foo");

    public void Bar()
    {
        namedLock.Lock();
        //...
        namedLock.Unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks oleksii, I just thought I might be missing something obvious. I like your solution it seems very elegant to me!